# Environment variables: Pod vs Container. Trying to access Container envvar with Python os.getenv

Tags: python, kubernetes, environment-variables

I have deployed a Pod with several containers. In my Pod I have certain environment variables that I can access in Python script with `os.getenv()`. However, if I try to use `os.getenv` to access the Container's environment variables I get an error stating they don't exist (NoneType). When I write `kubectl describe pod <POD_Name>` I see that all the environment variables (both Pod and Container) are set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but if you share the pod yaml (redacted if needed) we might be able to point out where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in creating helm tests. In order to get the environment variables from the containers in a helm test then the environment variables need to be duplicated in the test.yaml file or injected from a shared configmap.

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer I would like to add a little theory.

See [this documentation about ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/).

> A ConfigMap is an API object used to store non-confidential data in key-value pairs. [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) can consume ConfigMaps as environment variables, command-line arguments, or as configuration files in a [volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#:%7E:text=env%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Define%20the,key%20to%20fetch.) one can find also an example of Pod that uses values from ConfigMap to configure a Pod:

```yaml
      env:
        # Define the environment variable
        - name: PLAYER_INITIAL_LIVES # Notice that the case is different here
                                     # from the key name in the ConfigMap.
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: game-demo           # The ConfigMap this value comes from.
              key: player_initial_lives # The key to fetch.
```